# Fastest way to query all data from 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Say i have 3 tables like so:

`Table 1`

```
|Id|Date |Data1|
|--|---- |-----|
|1 |24/05|Some1|
```

`Table 2`

```
|Id|Date |Data2|
|--|---- |-----|
|1 |24/05|Some2|
|1 |12/06|Some2|
```

`Table 3`

```
|Id|Date |Data3|
|--|---- |-----|
|1 |24/05|Some3|
|1 |14/06|Some3|
```

How do i go about getting the results like so:

```
|Id|Date |Data1|Data2|Data3|
|--|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|1 |24/05|Some1|Some2|Some3|
|1 |12/06|NULL |Some2|NULL |
|1 |14/06|NULL |NULL |Some3|
```

Using MS SQL.

What i came up with is

```
SELECT Id, Date, Data1, Data2, Data3 FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id AND Table1.Date = Table2.Date
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Id = Table3.Id AND Table1.Date = Table3.Date
UNION 
SELECT Id, Date, Data1, Data2, Data3 FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Id AND Table2.Date = Table1.Date
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table2.Id = Table3.Id AND Table2.Date = Table3.Date
UNION 
SELECT Id, Date, Data1, Data2, Data3 FROM Table3
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Id AND Table3.Date = Table3.Date
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table3.Id = Table2.Id AND Table3.Date = Table2.Date
```

Is there a nicer way to query the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    id       = coalesce(t1.id,t2.id,t3.id) 
  , [date]   = coalesce(t1.[date],t2.[date],t3.[date]) 
  , t1.Data1
  , t2.Data2
  , t3.Data3
from Table1 t1
  full join Table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id 
   and t1.[date]=t2.[date]
  full join Table3 t3
    on (t1.id = t3.id and t1.[date]=t3.[date])
    or (t2.id = t3.id and t2.[date]=t3.[date])
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ATCJ12705

returns:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | date  | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | 24/05 | Some1 | Some2 | Some3 |
|  1 | 12/06 | NULL  | Some2 | NULL  |
|  1 | 14/06 | NULL  | NULL  | Some3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: why do we need to coalesce id? E.g. Wouldnt just `t1.id` suffice?

Comment: @zaitsman nope. Besides, you can try it on the demo and find out real quick.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way is to do a collation on all dates and ids in a temporary table and then put data against it.

```
Select T.id,T.date, T1.Data1,T2.Data2,T3.Data3
FROM
    (
        select id,date from Table1
        UNION 
        select id,date from Table2
        UNION 
        select id,date from Table3
    ) T
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 on T.id=T1.id and T.date=T1.date
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 on T.id=T2.id and T.date=T2.date
LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 on T.id=T3.id and T.date=T3.date
ORDER BY T.id,T.date
```

Number of JOINs= number of unique Tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each table has only 1 row for each id and date, putting null values in an UNION and choosing the MAX value can achieve the same:

```
create table #t1 (id int, [date] nvarchar(5), data1 nvarchar(10))
create table #t2 (id int, [date] nvarchar(5), data2 nvarchar(10))
create table #t3 (id int, [date] nvarchar(5), data3 nvarchar(10))

insert into #t1 values (1, '24/05', 'Some1')
insert into #t2 values (1, '24/05', 'Some2'),  (1, '12/06', 'Some2')
insert into #t3 values  (1, '24/05', 'Some3'),  (1, '14/06', 'Some3')

select a.id, a.[date], max(a.data1) as [Data1], max(a.data2) as [Data2], max(a.data3) as [Data3]
from 
( 
select id, [date], [data1] as [Data1], Null as [Data2], null as [Data3] from #t1
union
select id, [date], null as [Data1], [data2] as [Data2], null as [Data3] from #t2
union
select id, [date], null as [Data1], Null as [Data2], [Data3] as [Data3] from #t3
) a
group by a.id, a.[date]
```

Comment: as it is clearly shown in the example a table can have more than one row for the same id